# Adding controls dynamically on user selection in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown which consists of all the controls names like textbox , label , combobox , dropdown list...etc.
if in the starting one label control is placed on form,on user selection of control name in dropdown list ,that label control should be replaced with the user selected control dynamically...like this,what ever control user wants to keep can keep just by selecting dropdow

---

i need the controls to be dynamic.that is only the requirement.whenever a person ,say admin want to change the controls from CMS,he can easily change with the selection.

Comment: Do all those controls already exist? Windows Form application or ASP.NET website? Please give more details and try to clarify what you want as well.

Comment: is this a windows forms or an asp.net application?

Comment: this is a web application.i want to create the controls on user selection.so they will not be existing before

Comment: if a form is there where it contains name textbox,email textbox and submit button.now when admin wants to change the name textbox to a label in future,on selecting in dropdown ,he must be able to change the control from textbox to label.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use some Javascript magic for this. Whats the specific requirement?

Comment: i need the controls to be dynamic.that is only the requirement.whenever a person ,say admin want to change the controls from CMS,he can easily change with the selection.

Comment: if a form is there where it contains name textbox,email textbox and submit button.now when admin wants to change the name textbox to a label in future,on selecting in dropdown ,he must be able to change the control from textbox to label.

Comment: You cant achieve that by copy pasting code, you'd have to think and learn for yourself. 

A select element has an onChanged event, listen to that and modify the DOM as you need. You can create new elements using `document.createElement`, or setting the innerHTML of another DOMElement yourself.